# What Quick Job category are Target Assault Races under?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

In *GTA Online*, I'm looking to join available lobbies hosting any [Target Assault](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Target_Assault) race using the in-game phone's 'Quick Job' functionality so that I could be 'on call' and continue to play Freemode while the game finds an available job for me.

I'm not sure which Quick Job category Target Assault Races are under since there are multiple racing-related categories listed under Quick Job, but no 'Target Assault Race' category specifically. I'm playing on the PC.